# Resumen de datos con tabla dinámica y dato dividido

Tags: excel, ciencia-de-datos, hoja-de-cálculo-tabla-dinámica

Tengo una duda de cómo poder resumir una lista de datos.

Dejo el enlace al archivo Excel: http://ge.tt/381feDj2.

La duda es, ¿Cómo poder determinar (resumir) el total de actividades por unidad considerando que una persona trabaja en 2 unidades?

Se podría definir que la persona que trabaja en **A/B** hace el **50%** de actividades para cada unidad.

Como la lista es muy extensa, la idea es poder automatizar, intenté con una tabla dinámica y no me dio resultado.

```
funcionario unidad
  UNO         A
  DOS         B
  TRES        C
 CUATRO      A/B

         DATOS ORIGINALES        |          DATOS CON UNIDAD
  fecha    funcionario actividad | UNIDAD   fecha    funcionario actividad
01/01/2017     UNO       CORRER  |    A   06/01/2017     UNO       CORRER
02/01/2017     UNO       BAILAR  |    A   11/01/2017     UNO       BAILAR
03/01/2017     DOS       SALTAR  |    B   18/01/2017     DOS       SALTAR
04/01/2017     DOS       SALTAR  |    B   11/01/2017     DOS       SALTAR
05/01/2017     TRES      CORRER  |    C   07/01/2017     TRES      CORRER
06/01/2017     TRES      CORRER  |    C   05/01/2017     TRES      CORRER
07/01/2017     TRES      CORRER  |    C   10/01/2017     TRES      CORRER
08/01/2017     UNO       SALTAR  |    A   11/01/2017     UNO       SALTAR
09/01/2017     UNO       SALTAR  |    A   05/01/2017     UNO       SALTAR
10/01/2017     UNO       BAILAR  |    A   09/01/2017     UNO       BAILAR
11/01/2017    CUATRO     BAILAR  |   A/B  06/01/2017    CUATRO     BAILAR
12/01/2017     TRES      BAILAR  |    C   12/01/2017     TRES      BAILAR
13/01/2017     TRES      BAILAR  |    C   02/01/2017     TRES      BAILAR
14/01/2017    CUATRO     BAILAR  |   A/B  08/01/2017    CUATRO     BAILAR
15/01/2017     DOS       CORRER  |    B   01/01/2017     DOS       CORRER
16/01/2017     DOS       BAILAR  |    B   15/01/2017     DOS       BAILAR
17/01/2017     DOS       SALTAR  |    B   02/01/2017     DOS       SALTAR
18/01/2017     DOS       CORRER  |    B   17/01/2017     DOS       CORRER

1. Total de actividades por funcionario
2. Total de actividades por unidad
```

Comment: Por qué la tabla dinámica no te dio resultado? Yo sí creo que la tabla dinámica es el camino a seguir, pero su éxito o resultado está en cómo la definas

Comment: No da resultado por que para las actividades de los funcionarios que trabajan en A/B deben agregarse en 50% y 50% a A y. B... No se puede crear un subconjunto A/B.

Answer (score 0):

Para "determinar (resumir) el total de actividades por unidad considerando que una persona trabaja en 2 unidades", a continuación te comparto lo que yo hago en casos similares.

1. [Denormailizar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalizaci%C3%B3n_(base_de_datos)), es decir convertir el formato de los datos originales a formato de "`tabla simple`" aún y cuando se repitan datos, ya que lo que buscamos es optimizar la realización de los cálculos y no las transacciones u otros parámetros.

   En este caso, la `tabla simple` quedaría de la siguiente forma, se indican columna y luego los valores válidos entre llaves,

   1. Fecha {01/01/2017..18/01/2017}
   2. Funcionario {UNO,DOS,TRES,CUATRO}
   3. Actividad {BAILAR,CORRER,SALTAR}
   4. Unidad {A,B,C}
   5. Trabajo {0.5,1}

> NOTA: Ahora en lugar de tener un reglón para los funcionarios que en la tabla con Unidad tienen A/B en la columan Unidad, ahora deberás tener dos renglones, uno con A en la columna Unidad y otro con B en la columna Unidad , indicando en la columa Trabajo 0.5. En el resto de las columnas se repetirán los valores.

Ahora puedes aplicar la tabla dinámica usando funciones sencillas. Para el cálculo de "la actividades por unidad", hacer lo siguiente

- Agrega `Unidad` a *renglones*
- Agrega `Trabajo` a *valores* y usa la función sumar.

Para una descripción más detallada, revisa [Crear una tabla dinámica para analizar datos de una hoja de cálculo](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Crear-una-tabla-din%C3%A1mica-para-analizar-datos-de-una-hoja-de-c%C3%A1lculo-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).

Nota: Para manejar lo que yo llamo tabla simple, Excel tiene lo que llama [tabla de Excel](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Descripci%C3%B3n-general-de-las-tablas-de-Excel-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES).